# How get latiude and longitude of point?

Tags: annotations, uibutton, mkmapview, uitoolbar, mkpinannotationview

I am developing an iPhone Application in which i have provide Pin Annotation button on tool bar. When user click on button then pin will drop on center of map view. Now i want that user move that pin and place at their desired place and i will get latitude and longitude of that point. So how i define all these event with my map view?  How do that? I get this code for add annotation.

```
 - (void)addPinAnnotation:(id)sender {
UICRouteAnnotation *pinAnnotation = [[[UICRouteAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:[routeMapView centerCoordinate]
                                                                              title:nil
                                                                     annotationType:UICRouteAnnotationTypeWayPoint] autorelease];
[routeMapView addAnnotation:pinAnnotation];
```

}

How get latitude and longitude of that point?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    // Add annotation to map
    MKCoordinateRegion reg;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = newLocation.coordinate ;
    reg.center = location;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 1.5;
    span.longitudeDelta = 1.5;
    reg.span = span;
    reg.center=newLocation.coordinate;
    [self.mapView setRegion:reg animated:TRUE];
    annotation = [[myAnnotation  alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate title:@"Click > to set or drag to move"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [loading stopAnimating];
}
```